# how to clone the mongoose query object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am facing the problem of clone of the `mongoose query` object .`Javascript` the copy the one object into another object by `call-by-ref` but in my project there is scenario i need to copy one object into another object by `call-by-value.`

```
    var query=domain.User.find({
            deleted: false,
            role: role
        })

var query1=query;
```

> I have the scenario change in the query object is not reflected in `query1`. I google and try so many way to clone the object but it does't work.The query object is used in another function for pagination and `query1` object is used for count query.

1.I used to Object.clone(query1) error Object.clone is not function
 2.I used Object.assign(query1) but it does't works fine.
 3.I used other so many ways can anybody help me to sort this problem

Comment: If you can, u may use lodash _.clone methods : https://lodash.com/docs#clone or https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Comment: you said Object.assign(query1).......is not working? can you mention what happened with that?

Comment: @gvsharma change query1 reflects in query variable in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are trying to clone a cursor, but it is not the right approach, you probably just need to create another

like this:

```
var buildQuery = function() {
  return domain.User.find({
    deleted: false,
    role: role
  });
};

var query = buildQuery();
var query1 = buildQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks it will help me..but if you have some other alternate way that would be more efficient.

Comment: May be old, but here is better approach: const queryJson = query.getQuery(); YourShema.count(queryJson);

Answer (score 8):

Alternative solution using `merge` method:

```
const query = domain.User.find({
  deleted: false,
  role: role
}).skip(10).limit(10)

const countQuery = query.model.find().merge(query).skip(0).limit(0)

const [users, count] = await Promise.all([query, countQuery.count()])
```

Comment: This is really a better and complete solution. @Sergii any idea how to achieve the similar objective when query is of type aggregate?
Something which can replace the model.find() method?

Comment: @IrfanRaza never tried to do this for aggregation query but you will need to follow different way. Something like this should work: `const agg = User.aggregate().unwind('profile'); const copy = User.aggregate(agg.pipeline())`

Comment: Make sense. But would changing agg later will change the copy object as well? Just asking if you are aware about its behaviour? @Sergii

Comment: `agg.pipeline()` returns an array. It's pretty easy to copy it if you have such kind of issue: `agg.pipeline().slice(0)`

Answer (score 2):

This is work for me:

```
const qc = sourceQuery.toConstructor();
const clonedQuery = new qc();
```

This code work in pagination function where sourceQuery passed as parameter and i dont known what models used. Also it work with aggregations and complex queries.

```
  public async paging(
    query: mongoose.DocumentQuery<mongoose.Document[], mongoose.Document>,
    params,
    transformer: any = null
  ) {
    let page = Number(params.page);
    if (!page) page = 1;

    let page_size = Number(params.count);
    if (!page_size) page_size = 100;

    const qc = query.toConstructor();
    const cq = new qc();
    return cq.countDocuments().exec()
      .then(async (total) => {
        const s = params.sort;
        if (s) {
          query.sort(s);
        }
        query.limit(page_size);
        query.skip(page_size * (page - 1));
        let results = await query.exec();
        if (transformer) {
          results = await Promise.all(results.map((i) => transformer(i)));
        }
        const r = new DtoCollection();
        r.pages = Math.ceil(total / page_size);
        r.total = total;
        (r.results as any) = results;
        return r;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since mongoose v6 you can use [Query.prototype.clone](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#duplicate-query-execution)

E.g. for your code snippet:

```js
const query = domain.User.find({
  deleted: false,
  role: role
})

const query1 = query.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sergii Stotskyi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444935/7342188) works just fine and is very elegant, except that `count` is deprecated.

`countDocuments` or `estimatedDocumentCount` should be used instead.

However, this causes the error `the limit must be positive`. We can walk around this by set `limit` to a large integer.

```js
const query = domain.User.find({
  deleted: false,
  role: role
}).skip(10).limit(10)

const countQuery = query.model.find().merge(query).skip(0).limit(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

const [users, count] = await Promise.all([query, countQuery.countDocuments()])
```